# url forwarding updating a div instead of global redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I have to redirect the flow of my website to login page when user clicks any link in the page once the session is expired (either by time out or manually loggout out from another window)

I added the following piece of code in my main.gsp(included in every gsp)

```
<script>
  $.ajaxSetup({
            statusCode: {
            401: function(){

            // Redirect the to the login page.
            location.href = "/gra/login/auth";
            }
            }
            });
  </script>
```

This used to work fine before, but we did some changes to out application in this phase (oracle migration, new UI and also spring security plugin)

Now it doesnt forward the entire page to login page, but content is only refreshed in the target container which is updated by the link click (the logout page comes in that div only)
This is how it used to work without the above code.
How do I make this a global page forward?

Update: I just checked it in firebug and found that clicking a link after session timeout 
is generating a 302 (moved temporarily) code number in response and not 401 ?

Comment: no its not.. Iam not using Iframes..its nested divs

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent task for using grails Filters [(Documentation)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.6%20Filters).

The code below will intercept all controllers and all actions and `belore` they are invoked and check the session is valid. If it fails, it redirects to the login page.

You should change the condition in the `if` statement to check your session appropriately.

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       sessionCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
           before = {
              if (!session && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                  redirect(uri: '/gra/login/auth')
                  return false
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```